# PYTHON Attribute Error while running this GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

So, I'm following a tutorial on making a simple calculator, and I'm Getting an attribute error **AttributeError:'_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'displayframe'** , apparently, the attribute doesn't exist in the source code even if it has been defined? would be grateful if someone helped

````
from tkinter import * 

SMALL_FONT_STYLE = "Arial 16"
LIGHT_GRAY = "#F5F5F5"
LABEL_COLOR = "#25265E"
LARGE_FONT_STYLE = "Arial 40 bold"
WHITE = "#FFFFFF"

class Calculator(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("375x677")
        self.resizable(0,0)
        self.title("Calculator")

        self.total_expression = "0"
        self.current_expression = "0"

        self.total_label, self.label = self.create_display_labels()

        self.digits = {7:(1,1), 8:(1,2), 9:(1,3), 4:(2,1), 5:(2,2), 6:(2,3), 1:(3,1),2:(3,2), 3:(3,3), 0:(4,2), '.':(4,1)}
        self.create_digits_buttons()

        self.display_frame = self.create_display_frame()
        self.buttons_frame = self.create_buttons_frame()


    def create_display_labels(self):
        total_label = Label(self.display_frame, text=self.total_expression, anchor=E, bg=LIGHT_GRAY, fg=LABEL_COLOR, padx=24, font=SMALL_FONT_STYLE)
        total_label.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

        label = Label(self.display_frame, text=self.total_expression, anchor=E, bg=LIGHT_GRAY, fg=LABEL_COLOR, padx=24, font=LARGE_FONT_STYLE)
        label.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

        return total_label, label

    def create_display_frame(self):
        frame = Frame(self, height=221, bg=LIGHT_GRAY)
        frame.pack(expand=True, fill="both")
        return frame
    
    def create_buttons_frame(self):
        frame = Frame(self)
        frame.pack(expand=TRUE, fill="both")
        return frame

    def create_digits_buttons(self):
        for digit, grid_value in self.digits.items():
            button = Button(self.buttons_frame, text= str(digit), bg=WHITE, fg=LABEL_COLOR)
            button.grid(row = grid_value[0], column = grid_value[1], sticky=NSEW)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    Calc = Calculator()
    Calc.mainloop()```
````

Comment: The code you posted does not give the exact error that you mentioned in the question. Regardless, ask yourself when you create `self.display_frame` and when you use it when defining other widgets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is because you call `self.create_display_labels()` before calling `self.create_display_frame()`. You also call `self.create_digits_buttons()` before calling `self.create_buttons_frame()`.

Move `self.create_display_labels()` and `self.create_digits_buttons()` below `self.create_display_frame()` and `self.create_buttons_frame()`. Here is what `__init__()` should look like:

```py
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.geometry("375x677")
    self.resizable(0,0)
    self.title("Calculator")

    self.total_expression = "0"
    self.current_expression = "0"

    self.digits = {7:(1,1), 8:(1,2), 9:(1,3), 4:(2,1), 5:(2,2), 6:(2,3), 1:(3,1),2:(3,2), 3:(3,3), 0:(4,2), '.':(4,1)}

    self.display_frame = self.create_display_frame()
    self.buttons_frame = self.create_buttons_frame()

    self.create_digits_buttons() ### MOVED THIS LINE
    self.total_label, self.label = self.create_display_labels() ### MOVED THIS LINE
```

Comment: It's working now, such a stupid mistake, Thank you sir!

Comment: @ADI23 No problem! Learning from mistakes is much of what Stack Overflow is about. Please consider upvoting and accepting my answer if it is satisfactory. Happy coding!